# fetch last 12 months count and their variance using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
with sales as
(
select  COUNT(sale) As Number_of_sale, 
TO_CHAR(dates,'YYYY-MON') As Period

  from orders
    where dates between date '2020-03-01' and date '2020-03-31'
group by TO_CHAR(dates,'YYYY-MON') 

union all
select  COUNT(sale) As Number_of_sale,
TO_CHAR(dates,'YYYY-MON') As Period

  from orders
  where dates between date '2020-04-01' and date '2020-04-30'
group by TO_CHAR(dates,'YYYY-MON') 

)
select  Number_of_sale, period,
case when to_char(round((Number_of_sale-lag(Number_of_sale,1, Number_of_sale) over (order by period ))/ Number_of_sale*100,2), 'FM999999990D9999') <0 
then to_char(round(abs( Number_of_sale-lag(Number_of_sale,1, Number_of_sale) over (order by period ))/ Number_of_sale*100,2),'FM999999990D9999')||'%'||'  (Increase) '
when to_char(round((Number_of_sale-lag(Number_of_sale,1,Number_of_sale) over (order by period ))/Number_of_sale*100,2),'FM999999990D9999')>0 
then to_char(round(abs(Number_of_sale-lag(Number_of_sale,1, Number_of_sale) over (order by period ))/Number_of_sale*100,2),'FM999999990D9999')||'%'||'  (Decrease) '
END as variances
        from sales
        order by variances asc;
```

output i am getting

```
Number_of_sale  |  Period        |Variances
   50           |   2020-Mar         |  100%(increase)
   100          |   2020-Apr         |  Null
```

output i need:- i need last 12 month and their variance crossponding to the last month.

Comment: Please define what YOU mean by variance.  You are clearly not using the standard statistical definition.  Sample data and desired results would help as well.

Comment: Number_of_sale |  Period |Variances
     500       |   2020-apr    |  20%(increase(as per 2019-mar's data))
     375       |   2020-mar    |  0.2%(increase(as per 2019-feb's data))
     360       |   2020-feb    | Null
So on...

Comment: acc. to my query.. i am fetching records only for two months, and i need last 12 month.. records

Comment: Maybe you should put more than two months in your `dates BETWEEN x AND y` then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WITH bit of your query contains a bit of redundant unioning, and it might exclude dates with times on the end of the period. Consider this instead:

```
select  COUNT(sale) As Number_of_sale, 
TO_CHAR(dates,'YYYY-MON') As Period

  from orders
    where dates >= date '2019-03-01' and dates < date '2020-03-01'
group by TO_CHAR(dates,'YYYY-MON')
```

You don't need to union successive date ranges together, just use a bigger date range - your complaint was that you only got two months, but that's all you'd asked for! (From 1 mar to 31 mar, union from 1 apr to 30 apr, is two months)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to learn to work with dates as dates, only in extremely rare cases is conversion to string required (except for final display results). This is NOT one of them. Everything you have can be worked as dates.
With that out of the way you complain you want 12 months but your query only selects 2 months. If you want the last 12 you must select all 12.  You say you want variances but you are not calculating a statistical variance but the month-over-month difference (if how much does 1 month vary over the previous).

```
with parms  as (select trunc(date '&period_end_date','mon') dt from dual) 
   , sales as 
    ( select count(*) cnt 
           , trunc(dates,'mon') period
        from orders 
        cross join parms
       where trunc(dates,'mon') between add_months(dt, -12) 
                                         and last_day(dt)
       group by trunc(dates,'mon')
    ) 
select to_char(period, 'yyyy-Mon')  period
     , cnt                          number_of_sales 
     , to_char (round(abs(cnt - lag(cnt) over (order by period)) / cnt*100,2),'FM999999990D9999') ||
         case when cnt - lag(cnt) over (order by period) < 0 then ' %(Increase)'
              when cnt - lag(cnt) over (order by period) > 0 then ' %(Decrease)'
              else null
         end variances
  from sales  
order by variances asc;
```

**How it works**
The parms cte (in oracle 'subquery factoring') is basically because I'm lazy and don't want to enter the parameter value more than once. But it also has the advantage that regardless of actual date entered it 'returns' the 1st of the month. 
The sales cte counts number of sales for each month from the prior 12 months (add_months(dt, -12)) and the last day of the parameter date ( last_day(dt). Each of these functions automatically adjust for Feb 29th and the differing number of days in individual months. It gets the sales count for each month after truncating dates column to first of month.  
The main query then calculates the month to month difference with a simplified case to determine increase or decrease (left the same but I think it may be reversed and/or you need lead instead of lag).  
  
**Disclaimer:** Because you didn't actually supply table definitions not sample data it has not been tested.